# How to Add Additional Fields from Joined Table With a Nested Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following code that works perfectly counting the number of volunteers (not on staff) who completed more than one volunteer shift in the past year:

```
SELECT count(*) AS Volunteers
    FROM (
          SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y') > SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 year)) AND t2.status="Completed" AND t1.sector<>"Staff" THEN t2.id END) AS count
          FROM t2
          LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
          GROUP BY t2.id
          HAVING (count > 1)
         ) AS Volunteers;
```

But I can't figure out how to break it down beyond giving me just the aggregated count. I would like to see who recruited each of these people, for example -- but I can't figure out how to add that into this code. This obviously doesn't work:

```
SELECT t2.recruitedby, count(*) AS Volunteers
    FROM (
          SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN (STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y') > SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 year)) AND t2.status="Completed" AND t1.sector<>"Staff" THEN t2.id END) AS count
          FROM t2
          LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
          GROUP BY t2.id
          HAVING (count > 1)
         ) AS Volunteers;
```

Because obviously then you get the error `Unknown column 't2.recruitedby' in 'field list'` since I don't specify where the column should come from -- but if I try by adding "FROM t2" at the bottom, I get a "error in your SQL syntax" message. And I know I'd likely have to use `GROUP BY` again -- but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Finally, ideally, I'd like to add more columns to this query to break down volunteers from t1 as well -- so if a `LEFT JOIN` could be included somehow to do that as well, that'd be great -- but I wanted to ask the question without joining anything initially, so that I can at least get the first step.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have here can be accomplished with another join.  It would be much easier to create if you had a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)  That would allow for fewer mistakes, and easier discussion of the concepts.

Comment: Can you show us a little more of your table structure?

Comment: @jbarker2160   I can! What would be most helpful? The actual data is sensitive, but basically I have two tables of actual names (no numbers) -- one being all potential volunteers names (t1) and one being all shifts they completed (t2), which is attached to their names (and, for example, if I was a volunteer who completed 10 shifts, I would have 10 rows in t2 [one for each shift] as opposed to t1 where I only have one row). And both tables use the same ID for each person -- which is why a JOIN is so simple. Let me know if I could provide any more help!

Comment: *‘I would like to see who recruited each of these people’* – this bit is confusing. Without it I would assume you just want to count rows per `t2.recruitedby`. Could you clarify? Perhaps a small example would be enough.

Comment: @AndriyM       Thanks! So the way I see it I need the subquery because the number of volunteers needs to follow a specific set of criteria (e.g. more than two events in the past rolling calendar year, etc.) or else I'd just use a simple distinct count. But the recruited by field has names like "Smith, John" attached to each volunteer shift record -- so I'd like to see a simple first column of the person who recruited them next to how many volunteers that fit the criteria they have next to them. Does that help?

Comment: @AndriyM       Also the second query that @Programmer43229 posted below gets phenomenally close to what I need as long as you add `GROUP BY t2.recruitedby` to the end of it -- the only problem is that it overcounts even though it's using the same query as above which doesn't overcount, which is why it's a bit confusing if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the subquery? (grouped by 2 columns due to the chance of duplicate names)

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.recruitedby, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y') > SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 year
    AND t2.status="Completed"
    AND t1.sector<>"Staff"
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.recruitedby
HAVING (count > 1)
```

Edit: The above command returns unwanted results. If your query in your question returns the proper results for volunteers, how does this command do?

```
SELECT t2.recruitedby, COUNT(Volunteers.count) AS Volunteers
FROM (
    SELECT t2.id, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN (STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y') > SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 year))
        AND t2.status="Completed"
        AND t1.sector<>"Staff"
        THEN t2.id END) AS count
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t2.id
    HAVING (count > 1)
   ) AS Volunteers
JOIN t2 ON t2.id=Volunteers.id
```

Edit: the below query (ain't pretty) returns these rows:

```
Smith, Jane    2
Smith, John    1
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT recruiters.recruitedby, COUNT(Volunteers.id) AS Volunteers
FROM
(
    SELECT t2.id, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN (STR_TO_DATE(t2.date,'%m/%d/%Y') > SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 year))
        AND t2.status="Completed"
        AND t1.sector<>"Staff"
        THEN t2.id END) AS count
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t2.id
    HAVING (count > 1)
) AS Volunteers
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, recruitedby
    FROM t2
) AS recruiters
ON recruiters.id=Volunteers.id
GROUP BY recruiters.recruitedby
```

I don't think I've ever written a query quite like this one!

Comment: It seems like I do need the subquery. This example is more or less how it was, but it was over-inflating the numbers -- I couldn't really figure out why, but when I started using the subquery above, it gave me the correct sum. For example, your query yields a count of 2,309 -- when the actual sum and my first query gives the correct amount of 362.

Comment: My query returns 2,309 rows compared to 362 rows? I'm thinking my query returns the number of shifts the volunteers worked per recruiter?

Comment: @programmer53229 Yup -- that was just me looking at the aggregate. But if it did return 362 (like my query above), it would be almost exactly how I would have wanted it returned except I wouldn't have selected or grouped by t2.id because the IDs for each person are unique, so it would kind of defeat the purpose of grouping by "recruitedby."

Comment: That might be what it's doing? I changed `COUNT(1) AS count` to `COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS count` to see if it dropped it -- which it did, but it only dropped it to 1,456 -- still off by more than 1k.

Comment: I would also much prefer writing this without the subquery, since that would make it way easier to plug into a much larger query where I run other counts related to this stuff. But the problem then with this is that I'm using the `WHERE` clause and I can't restrict all the other parts of the query to what we have above as well, since that would make the other counts (not included here) too restrictive -- which is another reason why I assumed I needed the subquery.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry about that -- I didn't see your edit for a little while. But it's by far the closest I've gotten -- I just had to add a final line of `GROUP BY t2.recruitedby` at the end and it's the first time I did something like this with the subquery where I didn't get an error. Though it's still far more people total than the first query I posted above -- any idea why this code (even though it's the exact same subquery) would yield so many additional results?

Comment: @Ryan: If I understood all the explanations correctly, perhaps you should count `t1.id` instead of `t2.id` in the nested query (`COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN t1.id END)`). Also, you can probably avoid a join (but not a nested query) if you add `t2.recruitedby` both to the (nested) GROUP BY and SELECT. You will then need to group by `recruitedby` in the outer query (as I said, without the join). If necessary, I'll try and show you what I mean a little later when I have a free minute.

Comment: @AndriyM       Thanks! It'd be great to see what you mean more specifically in query-form. In the mean time, I'm going to try and play around with SQL Fiddle so it's easier to see -- though I've never used it before.

Comment: @programmer43229 I created a sample SQL Fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc11/1/0 -- hopefully it helps! As you can see, it's saying there are 6 volunteers for Jane and 4 for John -- where it's counting the number of events they completed, instead of the people who completed them. Also if it were doing that I would have assumed it would have counted 5 instead of 6 for Jane since one of her completed events is over a year ago.

Comment: @Ryan: Oh, your SQL Fiddle really helped to see the issue. I thought (maybe programmer43229 did too) that `t2.id` was the ID of a volunteer, but it is not (because you say that John has 4 but there are only 2 distinct IDs for John). How do you tell one volunteer from another?

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: @AndriyM       Sorry for the lack of clarity! The ID is distinct per volunteer -- but they show up multiple times if they've done multiple things.

Comment: @programmer43229 Thank you so much for the help! This works great. Didn't think a `JOIN` was going to be necessary at the end, but it looks like it was. Way more complicated than I initially thought when I asked this question. Hopefully it'll still work if I embed it within other queries too. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ryan: If the result returned by the latest suggestion in this answer is correct, then here's the solution I meant to show before I saw your SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc11/22. (Well, not entirely, as it counts `t2.id` rather than `t1.id` that I suggested before.) I'm not sure if it is correct at all times but at least it returns the same results as the solution you've accepted. You'll need to test it against various cases if you think it may be relevant. And sorry about the delay.